# Reusing database connection object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this function to connect to my MySQL db when needed, and also to re-use the same connection object for any further query I might need in the same php script.

```
function cnn() {
    static $pdo;
    if(!isset($pdo)) {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, 30);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $pdo;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            http_response_code(503);
            echo $e->getCode.': '.$e->getMessage();
            die(); //or whatever error handler you use
        }
    } else {
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

First query (object is created)

```
echo cnn()->query('SELECT firstname FROM user WHERE id=4;')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)
```

Second query (object is reused)

```
echo cnn()->query('SELECT title FROM news WHERE id=516;')->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN)
```

Do you agree on this approach? Do you think it can be optimized? Thanks for your opinions.

Comment: What if you need to close that connection? How do you want to determine if it is active (not closed) ?

Comment: How far do you want it to be optimized ? In terms of REALLY REALLY little optimization, you should store it in a temporary variable, it would be one assembly `MOVE` instead of a `CALL` and a `BRANCH`, but hey, it's like one µs. =D

Comment: @CORRUPT normally, PHP would close the connection when the script ends. In this case, i'm using persistent connections (line 6), which means that the connections are not closed at the end of the script, but are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using the same credentials. Still, I guess it wouldn't hurt to add a parameter that, if true, sets $pdo to null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with the method, though many people will tell you that this "singleton" approach is bad, bad.

However, I disagree with your implementation. It should be:

```
function cnn() {
    static $pdo;
    if(!$pdo) {
        $conf = array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 30,
                  PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
                  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
            );
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $conf);
    } 
    return $pdo;
}
```

Also, it looks sensible to move handler code into *handler* (and **of course** without echoing the error unconditionally!)

```
function my_exceptionHandler($exception) {
    http_response_code(503);
    if (ini_get('display_errors')) {
        echo $e->getMessage().$e->getTrace();
    } else {
        log_error($e->getMessage().$e->getTrace());
    }
    die(); //or whatever error handler you use
}
set_exception_handler("my_exceptionHandler");
```

Also, I'd extend it to accept a parameter to make several connections possible.

Comment: Thanks for your code. One question, though: What would be the benefits of making several connections possible? (assuming that there is only one db)

Comment: assume you have several db to connect.